# Success rates or reviews of Brain Working Recursive Therapy (BWRT), and number of sessions needed on average

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, brain, hypnosis

Brain Working Recursive Therapy (BWRT), introduced by hypnotherapist Terrence Watts in 2011, is a brand new form of therapy. Hence, my internet search doesn't seem to give me any idea of how successful it really is. Here's a link to the official page of BWRT: https://www.bwrt.org/. It hasn't got a wikipidea page yet.

How many sessions of BWRT does one need in general to cure one specific problem?

If you could cite any links or even your personal experience, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [client testimonials](https://www.bwrt.org/pages/client-testimonials) on the website you provided it looks like it varies from 1 session to a few more.  Like any other therapy it seems to depend on the client and problem being dealt with.

You could ask the therapist how many sessions you are likely to need for your problem in order to find out whether you would like to go ahead or not.

I am really interested in this and I am going to look at this therapy in some detail as it is interesting to me considering it is supposedly not a remodel of NLP, EFT, TFT, WSN, SD, EMDR, Hypnosis, Reiki, Meridian/Energy therapies, Noesiology, Chinosis or any other style of therapy according to the home page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had 3 sessions of this over the Skype (apart from 2 hypnosis), and they did feel great. I still don't have enough evidence whether it's worked or not. But I did feel the therapist was very dedicated and it felt its power on the spot-it made me very emotional on the spot. But again, I've to see the problem for which I had the sessions is still there or not. 

I've had experience with hypnosis, and I'd say it got potential to work. But Reiki-the less I say, the better. I've Reiki I myself, and I applied it to myself as well as got it from other people.

Comment: Reiki didn't have an iota of result on me. I also had several other energy healing (reconnective, Kam Yuen, holistic), and I'd NEVER use them again. The practitioners charge a lot of money (one hour reconnective-60€, one hour of Kam Yuen-85€, where one hour BWRT-60€), but it 's never solved the problem, but both hypnosis and BWRT, I feel have got great potential to solve the problem at hand. And you can see they indeed did for many other people. Most people in the so-called the spirituality or energy healing circles are there to take your money-beware. I'm saying this from my own experience.

Comment: The energy healers can't explain their work, and also looking on the internet, you'll almost never find a problem they solved, where you'll see both hypnosis and BWRT did solve the problem.

BWRT is ENTIRELY different from hypnosis or any type of energy healing. It's based on science, look up Terrance Watts, he even got a youtube video talking about this.So it's not a remodel of the said modalities at all.